# ddd fails to connect to X Window: Is it a bug or a local misconfiguration?

Tags: arch-linux, x11

I am currently analyzing a problem where `ddd` hangs because it cannot connect to X Window. Here is the output of strace:

```
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, 20) = 0
getpeername(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path=@"/tmp/.X11-unix/X0"}, [20]) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="terra-arch", ...}) = 0
access("/home/phil/.Xauthority", R_OK)  = 0
open("/home/phil/.Xauthority", O_RDONLY) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
read(5, "\1\0\0\nterra-arch\0\0010\0\22MIT-MAGIC-COO"..., 4096) = 55
read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(5)                                = 0
getsockname(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, NULL}, [2]) = 0
fcntl(4, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(4, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
fcntl(4, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN|POLLOUT}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=4, revents=POLLOUT}])
writev(4, [{"...", 12}, {"", 0}, {"MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1", 18}, {"...", 2}, {"...", 16}, {"...", 0}], 6) = 48
recvmsg(4, 0x7ffc641c6e80, 0)           = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

Before the recvmsg call, it communicates with the "/tmp/.X11-unix/X0" socket and sends a `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` with a writev call. Then it loops forever (the recvmsg call keeps failing).

It worked a short while ago, `ddd` is the only application that seems to be affected. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the [XWindow authorization protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization#Cookie-based_access).

I am using Arch Linux. Not sure if it is related but xorg-server was recently updated:

```
ls -alhgtr /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-*
...
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  27K Mar 25 10:01 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-server-common-1.18.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1.3M Mar 25 10:01 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-server-1.18.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 708K Mar 25 10:01 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-server-xvfb-1.18.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  17K Apr  1 18:25 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-xinit-1.3.4-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 732K Apr  5 19:36 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-server-xvfb-1.18.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  27K Apr  5 19:36 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-server-common-1.18.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root 1.3M Apr  5 19:36 /var/cache/pacman/pkg/xorg-server-1.18.3-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

`/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` exists and it owned by root:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix
total 0
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr  5 21:22 X0
```

If I run `sudo ddd`, it works.

**I am not sure whether I should write a bug report, or if it is an error on my local system.** Can you help me narrow it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a configuration issue. Moving the `~/.ddd` directory so that `ddd` used a fresh configuration, solved the problem.

That explains why it worked with sudo, as it was executed as the root user which did not have a messed up configuration.

Something worth mentioning is that my interpretation of the `strace` output was also not correct. It is normal behavior to see a loop of `recvmsg` returning `EAGAIN` ("Resource temporarily unavailable"). It only means that the application is polling the socket for events. That is how it communicates with X11.